# Linux bash: sed, awk, etc tools are matching end of line regex '$' as the terminal width

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I am dealing with rows of data which are rather long, and therefore have more characters than the terminal's width. When I use sed, awk, etc to append any character to the end of each line, it is matching the end of line wherever the terminal width is. So instead of appending the desired character to the end of each line, it's getting put somewhere in the middle of each line, where the terminal width cuts off.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add an example to your question? What you describe sounds rather weird.

Comment: Can you show a concrete example? I'm skeptical.

Comment: Perhap OP is copy-and-pasting the input into a terminal or editor which automatically inserts line breaks. Or some such.

Comment: That is simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your file has a `CRFL` (*carriage return* - *line feed* or `\r` - `\n`) line ending where not appropriate (for example a Windows file in Linux system or ... or ...). If you write more-than-a-terminal-widths worth of `a`s to a file (1. I'm on Linux and 2. do not press <kbd>enter</kbd> in the end of terminal, just once after all the many <kbd>a</kbd>s and after that one <kbd>enter</kbd> press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>):

```
$ cat > pure_file
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[the only enter and ctrl-D goes here]
```

Your file-ending looks like this:

```
...aaaaLF
```

Then you add a `CR` to the end:

```
$ awk '{print $0 "\r"}' pure_file > cr_infected_file
```

(or just use `unix2dos` above) and your file ending looks like this:

```
...aaaaCRLF
```

Now add character `X` to the end of it:

```
$ awk '{print $0 "X"}' cr_infected_file
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

and the tail looks (added 2 spaces around `X` for your reading pleasure):

```
...aaaaCR X LF
```

What happens is that first all the `a`s get outputed, then `CR` *returns the carriage* to the beginning of line (*current line*, line 2 on your terminal) and then the `X` get outputed.